# Unity : Initializing Microsoft Media Foundation failed

Tags: video, unity-game-engine

I imported H264 .mp4 video in unity Assets folder. Every time I select the video
I get this error:

`Initializing Microsoft Media Foundation failed.  It seems that the Microsoft Media Foundation is not installed on this machine or a newer version of Microsoft Media Foundation is required.  To install the necessary libraries please install the Media Feature Pack from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/result.aspx?q=Media+Feature+Pack for your version of Windows.`

I installed Media Foundation as well as Media Feature Pack and restarted windows but I still get this error. Please somebody help me.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same issue in the past with a Windows 10 N installation.

The link I found following Unity's search link didn't do the job for me:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48231 (Won't work)

And then I searched manually with Google and found another link to a 64-bit installer (it was a completely different installer) that did the job.

[https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack](http://%20https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack) (Worked for me)

One notable difference between that one that didn't work and the one that did is that the one that worked, asked me to restart my computer. After restarting, I imported my videos without issues.